# ER Model: How is this an example of a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: relationship, entity-relationship

I'm reading *Database Systems Concepts 6e* by Silberschatz and Sudarshan and learning about relationships in the entity-relationship model.

One chapter on cardinality has the following figure, with an accompanying explanation:

[image]

> For example, consider Figure 7.10. The line between advisor and student has a
>   cardinality constraint of 1..1, meaning the minimum and the maximum cardinality
>   are both 1. **That is, each student must have exactly one advisor.** The limit 0..∗
>   on the line between advisor and instructor indicates that **an instructor can have
>   zero or more students.** Thus, the relationship advisor is one-to-many from instructor
>   to student, and further the participation of student in advisor is total, implying
>   that a student must have an advisor.

The confusing parts are in bold. Per another book I've been reading (*Database Systems* by Connolly and Begg), the above would be read as:

"An instructor advises one student. Each student can have zero or more advisors."

Here's an example of a diagram from the Connolly book to illustrate my point:

[image]

What's the correct way to read the first diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The subtle difference lies in the use of a **noun** to represent a relationship versus the use of a **verb** to represent a relationship. Both books are correct. The first book uses a noun (advisor); the second uses a verb.

For instructors and students participating in the "advisor" relationship, it makes sense to say that an instructor participates in that relationship anywhere from 0 to many times. However, a student may only participate once in that relationship (assuming a student cannot have more than one advisor). Thus, this is a 1-to-many relationship.

When we use a noun in this manner, it makes sense to keep the (min, max) notation closest to the entity to which it applies.

But this can be equivalently expressed with the verb "advises," where an instructor advises one or more students, but a student is advised by at most one instructor. In this uni-directional relationship defined by a verb, it makes more sense to place the instructor's participation near the student (the entity being "verbed," so to speak, in the relationship).